# Secret Cholent ingredient

Tags: food, product-recommendation

Does anyone know of any secret cholent ingredients to give it a knock out taste?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I told you, then it wouldn't be a secret.

;)

But anyway, one secret ingredient is Shabbos. See [Shabbat 119a](http://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_119.html):

> The emperor said to R. Joshua b. Hanania,29  'Why has the Sabbath dish such a fragrant odour?' 'We have a certain seasoning,' replied he, 'called the Sabbath, which we put into it, and that gives it a fragrant odour.' 'Give us some of it,' asked he. 'To him who keeps the Sabbath,' retorted he, 'it is efficacious; but to him who does not keep the Sabbath it is of no use.'

Comment: There is a pirush I fail to remember which one that says this Gemara is referring to Peper because we know there are two trees that listen to Hashem when he said the Bark and the fruit should have the same taste one Esrog hence we use it on Sukkos and Pepper has the Zchus of beisng used as the spice of Shabbos

Comment: Please can you explain
Where did Hashem say that the Bark and fruit should have the same taste
Where does it say that one of the trees that listened was pepper
Where does it say that pepper has the same tast as its bark

Comment: @R'Rafi, re "Where did Hashem say that the Bark and fruit should have the same taste", please see _Rashi_ to _B'reshis_ 1:11, http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165/showrashi/true#v8187.

Answer (score 3):

You're not the first to ask this question... [Google: "Secret Cholent Ingredient"](http://www.google.com/search?q=secret+cholent+ingredient&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 3):

I heard that a secret ingredient for cholent is beer.

Answer (score 1):

If you like it sweet some add Coca Cola. Some add peanut butter and jelly. Some add brown sugar. Others add honey. I have even heard of adding molasses.

If you like it hot, some add Tabasco Sauce. If you want to blow the roof off then add Habanaro Sauce.

Comment: I once cut in apples for sweetness. I can highly recommend it... as something you _not_ try.

Comment: Peanut butter and jelly? Really?

Comment: Tzvi, I kid you not!